# Is there a convention for when to use synchronous functions in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making some modules in Node.js and wondered: "Is there a convention for when to use return statements in Node.js?".

From what I understand return statements should be avoided since they would make the process a blocking operation, but is there a guideline to when they should be used, and when one should stick to callbacks?

Comment: I don't understand - don't you need to use return when you need to return a value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the use of return statement inside a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562679/what-is-the-use-of-return-statement-inside-a-function)

Comment: P.S. Even without a return statement a function still returns _something_, i.e., undefined. Functions don't automatically become asynchronous when you don't have an explicit return.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that I meant as to opposed to when one should stick to callbacks.

Comment: I edited the question title, so it can be better understood in the overwiew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether something is "Blocking" or not is up to you -- does it take much time?

Any IO operation should be considered blocking, as it relies on something outside the script (which could take any amount of time).

If your own script were to say, loop over something a couple hundred times (And you know this to take more than a fraction of a second) you might consider it blocking.

- If a method is blocking, it should accept a 'callback' parameter, and
  call that asynchronously.
- If a method is non-blocking, it should not
  accept a 'callback' paramater, and should have at least one 'return'
  statement.

Your convention should simply be that you know a function is asynchronous because it accepts a callback.

Comment: Note that an asynchronous function (who accepts a callback parameter) may also have a return, which would return itself; good for 'chaining'

Comment: I actually only came to those realisations about the conventions etc. over the last 2 months while learning Node.js myself :)

Comment: Why blocking code should and non blocking shouldn't accept callback? Isn't it the other way round? Is that a typo in the bulleted points

Comment: No that's the way it should work. If a function is non-blocking, you can use it like any regular function -- that is, wait for it to 'return' from it's processing. If a function is blocking you want to proceed with serving other things, and have it perform the callback once it's done.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a "cheap" operation, that's perfectly fine. Any operations which are performed multiple times where you're not doing CPU-intensive operations can (and often should) be refactored into a "normal" function. This is fine:

```
function add(x, y) { return x + y; }
```

This is not:

```
function fib(n) {
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    // this may take a long time if n is large
    return fib(n - 1) + fib (n - 2);
}
```

A possible implementation of fib would take a function to return the result as a parameter, and spread the calculation over multiple calls. Something like the code below, from the book "[Node Web Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/184951514X)":

```
function fib(n, done) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        done(1);
    } else {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            fib(n - 1, function(val1) {
                process.nextTick(function() {
                    fib(n - 2, function(val2) {
                        done(val1 + val2);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Where the thread wouldn't be blocked for long.

Yes, a better alternative would be to implement fibonacci in the iterative way, not the recursive one. But this is just to demonstrate how one could "split" a CPU-heavy function.

Comment: Thanks! (Although I might say that the O(2^n) example was a bit obvious)

Comment: @Esailija, you can change the recursion to any CPU-intensive function. Recursion was just easy to implement. If you know that the recursion is quick, it may even be ok as well.